# Selecting unique rows in a set of two possibilities

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-server, database, postgresql

The problem itself is simple, but I can't figure out a solution that does it in one query, and here's my "abstraction" of the problem to allow for a simpler explanation:

**I will let my original explenation stand, but here's a set of sample data and the result i expect:**

Ok, so here's some sample data, i separated pairs by a blank line

```
-------------
| Key |  Col | (Together they from a Unique Pair)
--------------
|  1     Foo |
|  1     Bar |
|            |
|  2     Foo |
|            |
|  3     Bar |
|            |
|  4     Foo |
|  4     Bar |
--------------
```

And the result I would expect, **after running the query once**, it need to be able to select this result set in one query:

```
1 - Foo
2 - Foo
3 - Bar
4 - Foo
```

*Original explenation:*

I have a table, call it `TABLE` where I have a two columns say `ID` and `NAME` which together form the primary key of the table. Now I want to select something where `ID=1` and then first checks if it can find a row where `NAME` has the value "John", if "John" does not exist it should look for a row where `NAME` is "Bruce" - but only return "John" if both "Bruce" and "John" exists or only "John" exists of course.

Also note that it should be able to return several rows per query that match the above criteria but with different ID/Name-combinations of course, and that the above explanation is just a simplification of the real problem.

I could be completely blinded by my own code and line of thought but I just can't figure this out.

Comment: Could you please clarify this question by giving an example? i.e. giving minimal data sets and the solutions you want to achieve from them?

Comment: How cross platform do you require the answer to be?  I could come up with something that would work in SQL Server, but wouldn't in MySQL...

Comment: Georgi: I clarified the example with some example data and the result i would expect after one query
AviewAnew: Anything is helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fairly similar to what you wrote, but should be fairly speedy as NOT EXISTS is more efficient, in this case, than NOT IN...

```
mysql> select * from foo;
+----+-----+
| id | col |
+----+-----+
|  1 | Bar | 
|  1 | Foo | 
|  2 | Foo | 
|  3 | Bar | 
|  4 | Bar | 
|  4 | Foo | 
+----+-----+

SELECT id
     , col
  FROM foo f1 
 WHERE col = 'Foo' 
  OR ( col = 'Bar' AND NOT EXISTS( SELECT * 
                                     FROM foo f2
                                    WHERE f1.id  = f2.id 
                                      AND f2.col = 'Foo' 
                                 ) 
     ); 

+----+-----+
| id | col |
+----+-----+
|  1 | Foo | 
|  2 | Foo | 
|  3 | Bar | 
|  4 | Foo | 
+----+-----+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can join the initial table to itself with an OUTER JOIN like this:

```
create table #mytest
   (
   id           int,
   Name         varchar(20)
   );
go

insert into #mytest values (1,'Foo');
insert into #mytest values (1,'Bar');
insert into #mytest values (2,'Foo');
insert into #mytest values (3,'Bar');
insert into #mytest values (4,'Foo');
insert into #mytest values (4,'Bar');
go

select distinct
   sc.id,
   isnull(fc.Name, sc.Name) sel_name
from
   #mytest sc

   LEFT OUTER JOIN #mytest fc
      on (fc.id = sc.id
          and fc.Name = 'Foo')
```

like that.

Comment: i seem to get an error when trying this in mysql, postgre only?

Comment: I tested it in SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 1):

No need to make this overly complex, you can just use `MAX()` and `group by ...`

```
select id, max(col) from foo group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select top 1 * from (
SELECT 1 as num, * FROM TABLE WHERE ID = 1 AND NAME = 'John'
union 
SELECT 2 as num, * FROM TABLE WHERE ID = 1 AND NAME = 'Bruce'
) t
order by num
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution myself, but it's kind of complex and slow - nor does it expand well to more advanced queries:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE name = "bruce"
OR (
    name = "john"
    AND NOT id
    IN (
        SELECT id
        FROM posts
        WHERE name = "bruce"
    )
)
```

No alternatives without heavy joins, etc. ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so here's some sample data, i separated pairs by a blank line

```
-------------
| Key |  Col | (Together they from a Unique Pair)
--------------
|  1     Foo |
|  1     Bar |
|            |
|  2     Foo |
|            |
|  3     Bar |
|            |
|  4     Foo |
|  4     Bar |
--------------
```

And the result I would expect:

```
1 - Foo
2 - Foo
3 - Bar
4 - Foo
```

I did solve it above, but that query is horribly inefficient for lager tables, any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that works in SQL Server 2005 and later.  It's a useful pattern where you want to choose the top row (or top n rows) based on a custom ordering.  This will let you not just choose among two values with custom priorities, but any number.  You can use the ROW_NUMBER() function and a CASE expression:

```
CREATE TABLE T (id int, col varchar(10));

INSERT T VALUES (1, 'Foo')
INSERT T VALUES (1, 'Bar')
INSERT T VALUES (2, 'Foo')
INSERT T VALUES (3, 'Bar')
INSERT T VALUES (4, 'Foo')
INSERT T VALUES (4, 'Bar')

SELECT id,col
FROM 
(SELECT id, col,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
    PARTITION BY id 
    ORDER BY 
    CASE col 
    WHEN 'Foo' THEN 1
    WHEN 'Bar' THEN 2 
    ELSE 3 END
    ) AS RowNum 
    FROM T
) AS X
WHERE RowNum = 1
ORDER BY id
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use joins instead of the exists and this may improve the query plan in cases where the optimizer is not smart enough:

```
SELECT f1.id
  ,f1.col
FROM foo f1 
LEFT JOIN foo f2
  ON f1.id = f2.id
  AND f2.col = 'Foo'
WHERE f1.col = 'Foo' 
  OR ( f1.col = 'Bar' AND f2.id IS NULL )
```

Answer (score -1):

In PostgreSQL, I believe it would be this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id) id, name
FROM mytable
ORDER BY id, name = 'John' DESC;
```

Update - false sorts before true - I had it backwards originally. Note that DISTINCT ON is a PostgreSQL feature and not part of standard SQL. What happens here is that it only shows you the first row for any given id that it comes across. Since we order by weather the name is John, rows named John will be selected over all other names.

With your second example, it would be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (key) key, col
FROM mytable
ORDER BY key, col = 'Foo' DESC;
```

This will give you:

```
1 - Foo
2 - Foo
3 - Bar
4 - Foo
```