# PHP mySQL - select unique value that not being used from dirrefent table

Tags: php, mysql, select, unique

**Updates : Please see below**

i have table: data

```
+-----------------------+--------------+-----------+
| State                 | d_country    | d_postcode|
+-----------------------+--------------+-----------+
| State1                | Country1     |      1111 | 
| State2                | Country2     |      2222 | 
| State3                | Country3     |      3333 | 
| State4                | Country4     |      4444 | 
+-----------------------+--------------+-----------+
```

And another table: user

```
+-----------------------+--------------+-----------+
| Name                  | u_country    | u_postcode|
+-----------------------+--------------+-----------+
| Name1                 | Country3     |      3333 | 
| Name2                 | Country5     |      5555 | 
| Name3                 |              |      6666 | 
| Name4                 | Country6     |      6666 | 
| Name5                 | Country6     |      6666 | 
+-----------------------+--------------+-----------+
```

What SQL should i use to:

<strike>Determine the number (count) of country that are not listed on table data. For example `u_postcode` is not listed in `d_postcode` is 5555 and 6666. It will return 2.</strike>

List down name and what country not available in table data yet.

**Updates**

3. I want to use grouping to filter postcode and make Name3 and Name4 as different rows.

For example:

```
    +-----------------------+--------------+-----------+
    | Name                  | u_country    | u_postcode|
    +-----------------------+--------------+-----------+ 
    | Name2                 | Country5     |      5555 | 
    | Name3                 |              |      6666 |
    | Name4                 | Country6     |      6666 | 
    +-----------------------+--------------+-----------+
```

Any possible idea?

**Remarks:** Corrected myself

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name, u_country, u_postcode FROM user 
WHERE u_postcode NOT IN (SELECT d_postcode FROM data)
```

Comment: Is this homework?  Looks like a homework question

Comment: no this is not homework. but anyone want to make this as homework also can. :). i know the hard way but want to use simplest query like 2-10 lines to achieve this. like JOIN, IN inner JOIN but do not know how to. still research. and not found :(

Comment: i have this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150610/selecting-unique-rows-in-a-set-of-two-possibilities and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190702/mysql-select-n-rows-but-with-only-unique-values-in-one-column related to my problem. it's near but i have no idea yet.

Comment: updates: i want Name3 and Name4 as unique value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this.

```
SELECT Name, u_country, u_postcode FROM user 
WHERE u_postcode NOT IN (SELECT d_postcode FROM data)
```

Hope it helps

Comment: @jerry: can i use another subquery or AND NOT EXISTS ? i'm affraid IN will be problem in performance. any idea?

Comment: if i put GROUP BY u_postcode, the u_country for Name 3 will be blank. how to display Name3 and Name4 as unique?

Comment: ok nvm, i solved uniqe problem using SELECT DISTINCT command. thank you all.